# \pause messes up the page layout

Tags: beamer, lists, itemize, pause

I'm having a frame in beamer which compiles just right when I do not use pauses (\pause). However, when I pause the different list items, the last items do not appear on the frame anymore (actually, they are outside the frame viewable part). It seems in some way beamer has some problem calculating how to fit the different items on the page when pauses are included.

Any idea how to avoid this problem?

EDIT : Some source code exhibiting the problem :

```
\documentclass[slidetop,11pt]{beamer}
\linespread{1.2}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Kubo-Greenwood Transport Formalism : Derivation}
Mott Method :
\begin{itemize}
\pause \item Electric field :
\footnotesize
\begin{equation*}
E(t) = E_0 cos(\omega t) u_x
\end{equation*}
\normalsize
\pause \item Coulomb gauge ($E=\delta A / \delta t$) :
\footnotesize
\begin{equation*}
A(t) = -\frac{E_0}{2 i \omega} (e^{i \omega t} - e^{-i \omega t}) u_x
\end{equation*}
\normalsize 
\pause \item First order perturbation of H :
\footnotesize
\begin{equation*}
\delta \widehat{H} (t) = \frac{2e \widehat{P}.A(t)}{2 m} = e \widehat{V}.A(t) = -\frac{e     E_0}{2 i \omega}(e^{i\omega t} - e^{-i \omega t}) \widehat{V}_x
\end{equation*}
\normalsize
\pause \item Transition from a state at t=0 to a state at t :
\footnotesize
\begin{equation*}
p_{nm} (t) = \frac{1}{\hbar^2} \left |\int_0^t d\tau e^{i(E_m-E_n) \tau / \hbar} \langle    m|\delta \widehat{H}(\tau)|n \rangle \right |^2
\end{equation*}
\normalsize
\pause \item At long times :
\footnotesize
\begin{equation*}
\frac{p_{nm}(t)}{t}  = \frac{2 \pi}{\hbar} \left(\frac{e2E_0}{2 \omega}\right)^2 \langle m|\widehat{V}_x|n \rangle \left[ \delta(E_m-E_n+\hbar \omega) +  \delta(E_m-E_n-\hbar     \omega)\right]
\end{equation*}
\normalsize
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And actually, thanks to your comment vanden to give a minimal amount of packages and comments, I managed to find the cause to this compilation error. It is the "\linespread{1.2}" command that messes things up when using \pause. If no fix available, I'll just comment it out I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is special syntax for item's - I've never tried `pause` with lists for that reason, but my guess is that it's causing trouble. Try removing all the pauses and replace `\begin{itemize}` with

```
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
```

This causes each item to be uncovered one by one. For more fine-grained control, instead of the above change, use e.g.

```
\item<3->
```

To make an item appear on slides 3 and above. There are other variants, see the Beamer user guide.

Answer (score 11):

That's some curious behaviour you observed! There's nothing inherently wrong in the syntax you use – I'll explain below why the output goes awry nevertheless. Neil's suggestion to use `\begin{itemize}[<+->]` is a great alternative to `\pause` in your example. If you want to use `\pause` all the same, then there's an easy fix: adding an empty line (or a `\par`)  *before* the offending `\pause`s will remove the additional vertical space, i.e., with

```
\pause\item
```

everything will be alright!

So, what causes the unwanted vertical space, and why on earth does an *additional* empty line *remove* the space? The problem is the combination of the displayed equation before and the `\item` after the `\pause`: after the display, TeX goes into horizontal mode, ready to build a new line of text. (This means that `\lastskip` is the last *horizontal* skip, which is `0pt`; see below.) The `\pause` puts some `\pdfliteral`s onto that line, and the `\item` ends it with a `\par`. This already gives one `\baselineskip` additional vertical space. On top of that, the `\item` adds an `\itemsep` (since `\lastskip` is `0pt` after the `\par`, see also below).

Without the `\pause`, these vertical spaces do not appear: the line following the displayed equation remains empty, so the `\par` doesn't add a `\baselineskip`. Moreover, the last vertical skip `\lastskip` is now `\belowdisplayskip` (or `\belowdisplayshortskip`), which is greater than an `\itemsep`, and `\item` is designed to not add `\itemsep` in this case.

And why does an empty line (i.e., a `\par`) before the `\pause` help? It ends the line that TeX started after the display, bringing TeX into vertical mode. That line is still empty, so no `\baselineskip` is added! Moreover, in *vertical* mode, `\lastskip` is again the last *vertical* skip `\belowdisplay(short)skip`. Now `\pause` does some `\unskip` magic so that the `\pdfliteral`s don't influence the `\lastskip`. Then `\item` issues another `\par`, but this doesn't do anything since TeX is already in vertical mode. Finally, `\lastskip` is still the same as without the `\pause`, so the `\item` doesn't add `\itemsep`, either.

**In summary:** `\pause` *may* go awry in horizontal mode (when TeX builds lines and paragraphs), but it's safe to use in vertical mode¹. That's why, a `\par` before a `\pause` can help in certain circumstances.

---

Just for the fun of it, here's a redefinition of `\pause` that looks ahead and inserts the `\par` automatically if it sees an `\item` (or a `\par`):

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\saved@pause\pause
  \renewcommand\pause{\futurelet\pause@next@char\pause@i}%
  \newcommand\pause@i{%
    \ifx\pause@next@char\par\par\fi
    \ifx\pause@next@char\item\par\fi
    \saved@pause
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

<sub>¹However, at the top of a `\vtop` box, when TeX is in *internal* vertical mode, `\pause` can [cause problems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75428).</sub>