# Behaviour of frametitle with raisebox

Tags: beamer, raise

See update below.
The following problem occurred while I was trying to alter the frametitle in beamer. (Actually  I want a picture in the Titlebar. I used a rule instead.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}  

\setbeamercolor*{frametitle in title}{fg=red, bg=black}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
    \vspace{-0.165ex}
    \mbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth, dp=1ex, ht=4.5ex, sep=1ex, colsep*=0pt]{frametitle in title}%
        \usebeamerfont{frametitle}
        \insertframetitle 
        \hfill
        \raisebox{-1.75ex}[\ht\strutbox][-\ht\strutbox]{\rule{5ex}{5ex}}
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        }%
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Hello}
Everythings fine here
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}%[fragile]
\frametitle{Can you see?} 
DO
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

So you can easily see that the red square representing the picture (I want it there) is shifted upwards on a fragile frame. I have no idea how fragile works (neither I have an idea about beamer but I was able to handle it so far.) Therefore I thought about an if-construct to figure out when fragil is on but... well there is no such construct available in user land...

thx for comments!

Update:
I just figured out, that the Problem has nothing to do with fragiles frames. 
It comes from letters with descender. So in fact I'm struggling to use `\raisebox` correctly.

Comment: Is this a question? May I suggest you delete this question and ask again for specific help with `\raisebox`?

Comment: I tidied up your question a bit, hope that's OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite right, the problem comes from the descender of the "y" in "Can you see". (It's quite natural that you were puzzled and first thought `fragile` to be the culprit; I had a [related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3345/1235) where I also didn't know what's happening. Juan A. Navarro called it "the dreadful Beamer's vertical alignment problem" ...)

*Solution:* Add a `\strut` to your frame titles, like this:

```
\frametitle{Hello\strut}
\frametitle{Can you see?\strut}
```

Then you see that the picture isn't shifted anymore. Now the picture is too high, but this can easily be solved by adapting the `\raisebox{-1.75ex}` of the picture.

Comment: Hi thanks so much... Now i use the following code (if s.o. has a related prob) `\usebeamerfont{frametitle} \insertframetitle\strut \hfill \raisebox{-2ex}[0pt][-\ht\strutbox ]{ \insertmylogo} `