# How to align `itemize` inside `NiceTabular` in `beamer`?

Tags: beamer, itemize, nicematrix

I am trying to use `NiceTabular` to create neat arrangements of slides. However, items inside `itemize` do not seem to properly align with the titles.

[image]

My questions are as follows

1. How to precisely align the first item in `itemize` with the title in the first column?
2. How to remove the empty line between the sample text and the itemization in tables?
3. I am basically trying to get `NiceTabular` to behave similar to `tabularx`, but with the awesome functionalities provided by `NiceTabular` (such as the ability to determine contents horizontal alignment with `p` columns in concise fashion and `hvlines`), I would love to use `NiceTabular`. Is it possible to get the second and third columns to fill the remaining of `\textwidth` automatically?

My MWE

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names},t]{beamer}

\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}

\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\newlength{\widthSideBar}
\setlength{\widthSideBar}{0mm}

\newlength{\widthTextMarginLeft}
\setlength{\widthTextMarginLeft}{10mm}
\newlength{\widthTextMarginRight}
\setlength{\widthTextMarginRight}{5mm}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=\widthTextMarginLeft, text margin right=\widthTextMarginRight}

\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=\widthSideBar, sidebar width right=0cm}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[triangle]

    % Adjusting \leftmargini for adjustbox environments
    \newlength{\widthItemizeIcon}
    \setlength{\widthItemizeIcon}{3.1mm}% good value 3.1mm
    \newcommand{\adjustboxItemize}{
        \addtolength{\leftmargini}{\widthItemizeIcon}
        \addtolength{\leftmargini}{\labelsep}}


\setlength{\leftmargini}{0mm}
\setlength{\parskip}{5mm}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\itemizecompact}{
    \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
        \setlength{\topsep}{0mm}
        \setlength{\itemsep}{0mm}
        \setlength{\parsep}{0mm}
    }
    \let\@listI\@listi
    \@listi
}
\makeatother

\newlength{\widthQuad}
\setlength{\widthQuad}{\widthof{\widthof{\quad}}}

\newcommand{\sampletext}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullamnec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante.}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
    
    \adjustboxItemize
    
    \itemizecompact
    
    {\noindent\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5.5pt}%
    \begin{NiceTabular}{@{}>{\bfseries}p[l]{2.5cm} p[l]{\dimexpr 0.63\linewidth - \tabcolsep - 2.5cm/2 \relax} @{\quad}p[l]{\dimexpr 0.37\linewidth - \tabcolsep - 2.5cm/2 - \widthQuad \relax}}
        
        One-line title & \blindlist{itemize} & \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth, valign=t]{example-image-a}
        \\
        
        One-line title & \sampletext \newline \blindlist{itemize} & \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth, valign=t]{example-image-b}
        \\
        
    \end{NiceTabular}
    }

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That problem is not specific to `nicematrix`. In fact, it's a problem of the `itemize` in a `minipage` in Beamer. See that [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3345/in-beamer-class-how-do-i-remove-the-additional-vertical-space-before-an-itemize?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the patch provided by Hendrik Vogt in that [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3345/in-beamer-class-how-do-i-remove-the-additional-vertical-space-before-an-itemize?rq=1), you have the expected output.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names},t]{beamer}


\makeatletter
\def\beamer@callorigitem{%
  \@ifnextchar[
    \beamer@@callorigitem
    {\beamer@origitem
     \if@minipage\else
       \kern0pt  % don't put the \kern at the top of a \minipage
     \fi
     \ignorespaces
    }%
  }
\newcommand*\if@minipage@and@vmode[2]{%
  \let\mini@vmode 0%
  \if@minipage\ifvmode
    \let\mini@vmode 1%
  \fi\fi
  \if\mini@vmode 1 #1\else #2\fi
}
% Redefine \beamerorig@set@color, \pgfsys@begininvisible and \pgfsys@endinvisible
% such that they don't act at the top of a \minipage;
% instead save the corresponding commands in \set@minipage@color ...
\def\set@minipage@color{}%
\let\save@beamerorig@set@color\beamerorig@set@color
\def\beamerorig@set@color{%
  \if@minipage@and@vmode{%
    \begingroup
    \def\reset@color{\relax}%
    \xdef\addto@minipage@color{\save@beamerorig@set@color}%
    \endgroup
    \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\set@minipage@color
                              \expandafter{\addto@minipage@color}%
    \aftergroup\reset@color
  }{%
    \save@beamerorig@set@color
  }%
}
\let\save@pgfsys@begininvisible\pgfsys@begininvisible
\let\save@pgfsys@endinvisible\pgfsys@endinvisible
\def\pgfsys@begininvisible{%
  \if@minipage@and@vmode
    {\g@addto@macro\set@minipage@color{\save@pgfsys@begininvisible}}
    {\save@pgfsys@begininvisible}%
}
\def\pgfsys@endinvisible{%
  \if@minipage@and@vmode
    {\g@addto@macro\set@minipage@color{\save@pgfsys@endinvisible}}
    {\save@pgfsys@endinvisible}%
}
% ... and execute them at the beginning of the first paragraph of the minipage
% (where \everypar issues \@minipagefalse).
\let\save@minipagefalse\@minipagefalse
\def\@minipagefalse{%
  \set@minipage@color
  \gdef\set@minipage@color{}%
  \save@minipagefalse
}
\makeatother



\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}

\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\newlength{\widthSideBar}
\setlength{\widthSideBar}{0mm}

\newlength{\widthTextMarginLeft}
\setlength{\widthTextMarginLeft}{10mm}
\newlength{\widthTextMarginRight}
\setlength{\widthTextMarginRight}{5mm}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=\widthTextMarginLeft, text margin right=\widthTextMarginRight}

\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=\widthSideBar, sidebar width right=0cm}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[triangle]

    % Adjusting \leftmargini for adjustbox environments
    \newlength{\widthItemizeIcon}
    \setlength{\widthItemizeIcon}{3.1mm}% good value 3.1mm
    \newcommand{\adjustboxItemize}{
        \addtolength{\leftmargini}{\widthItemizeIcon}
        \addtolength{\leftmargini}{\labelsep}}


\setlength{\leftmargini}{0mm}
\setlength{\parskip}{5mm}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\itemizecompact}{
    \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
        \setlength{\topsep}{0mm}
        \setlength{\itemsep}{0mm}
        \setlength{\parsep}{0mm}
    }
    \let\@listI\@listi
    \@listi
}
\makeatother

\newlength{\widthQuad}
\setlength{\widthQuad}{\widthof{\widthof{\quad}}}

\newcommand{\sampletext}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullamnec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante.}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
    
    \adjustboxItemize
    
    \itemizecompact
    
    {\noindent\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5.5pt}%
    \begin{NiceTabular}{@{}>{\bfseries}p[l]{2.5cm} p[l]{\dimexpr 0.63\linewidth - \tabcolsep - 2.5cm/2 \relax} @{\quad}p[l]{\dimexpr 0.37\linewidth - \tabcolsep - 2.5cm/2 - \widthQuad \relax}}
        
        One-line title & \blindlist{itemize} & \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth, valign=t]{example-image-a}
        \\
        
        One-line title & \sampletext \newline \blindlist{itemize} & \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth, valign=t]{example-image-b}
        \\
        
    \end{NiceTabular}
    }

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it acceptable if I had some time to chat with you regarding `NiceMatrix` package?

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh: Yes. Join the room `nicematrix`.