# Spacing in beamer seems to change when \pause is added

Tags: beamer, spacing, pause

`beamer` seems to sometimes add vertical space when I add `\pause` commands; an example is below. Is there some way to avoid that?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  Without pause:
  \[A\]\[B\]
  Not too much space between displayed equations.
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  With pause:
  \[A\]\pause\[B\]
  Too much space between the equations.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem is very similar as in this question: [`\pause` messes up the page layout](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1512).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, `\pause` inserts "something" on an empty line in your instance. You could get rid of it by "jumping back" a line using `\vspace*{-\baselineskip}` *before* `\pause`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  Without pause:
  \[A\]\[B\]
  Not too much space between displayed equations.
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  With pause:
  \[A\]\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\pause\[B\]
  Too much space between the equations.
\end{frame}
\end{document}​
```

Answer (score 5):

Usually it's not recommended to use one displayed equations right after the other. In such cases you would do something like

```
\begin{gather*}
A \\ B
\end{gather*}
```

The problem is that `\pause` doesn't work reliably in `amsmath` environments, but you can use the fix from [this answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75550):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\makeatletter
\let\save@measuring@true\measuring@true
\def\measuring@true{%
  \save@measuring@true
  \def\beamer@sortzero##1{\beamer@ifnextcharospec{\beamer@sortzeroread{##1}}{}}%
  \def\beamer@sortzeroread##1<##2>{}%
  \def\beamer@finalnospec{}%
  }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  Without pause:
  \begin{gather*}
    A \\
    B
  \end{gather*}
  Not too much space between displayed equations.
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  With pause:
  \begin{gather*}
    A \\ \pause
    B
  \end{gather*}
  Same space between the equations.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Let me point out that the spacing differs from the one you get with `\[A\]\[B\]`. On the one hand, `gather` doesn't "see" that the line `Without pause` is short, so it puts more vertical space between that line and `A`. On the other hand, the space between `A` and `B` becomes smaller; this can be adjusted by using `\\[1ex]` instead of `\\`. (Adjust the `1ex` to your needs.)

---

If you want to stick with two seperate displays: as Werner said, `\pause` inserts something (namely, one or two `\pdfliteral`s) on an otherwise empty line, which gives an additional vertical space of one `\baselineskip`. One can prevent TeX from ever putting this additional vertical space by using

```
\par\pause\noindent
```

instead of `\pause`: the `\par` ends the empty line after the first display, the `\noindent` keeps the empty line before the second display empty (and `\parskip` is zero in `beamer`); see also [this answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73729) for details.