# How to remove the unexpected vertical space in the theorem environment?

Tags: beamer, math-mode, spacing, theorems, pause

When I use `\pause` in `\[ \]` formula in the `theorem` environment, I get an unexpected extra space below the formula; see Theorem: Pause (formula). Now I remove it using `\vspace{-0.60}cm`, as in Theorem: Pause and Negative VSpace.

How to remove it without using `\vspace`?

```
\documentclass[beamer]{standalone}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{theorem}[No Pause]
    \[
      a + b = c
    \]
  \end{theorem}

  \begin{theorem}[Pause (formula)]
    \[
      a + b = \pause c
    \]
  \end{theorem}

  \begin{theorem}[Pause and Negative VSpace]
    \[
      a + b = \pause c
    \]
    \vspace{-0.60cm}
  \end{theorem}

  \begin{theorem}[Pause (text)]
    a + b = \pause c
  \end{theorem}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: beamer-pause-space]

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41509/15925 help? (There are two different answers).

Comment: @AndrewSwann Yes, thanks. However, I like the solution given by David Carlisle below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't traced fully and I'm not sure it's completely robust in all cases but you can keep the pause mechanics within the formula, so avoid starting a line after the display, by adding a group

[image]

```
\documentclass[beamer]{standalone}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{theorem}[No Pause]
    \[
      a + b = c
    \]
  \end{theorem}

  \begin{theorem}[Pause (formula)]
    \[
      {a + b = \pause c}
    \]
  \end{theorem}

  \begin{theorem}[Pause and Negative VSpace]
    \[
      a + b = \pause c
    \]
    \vspace{-0.60cm}
  \end{theorem}

  \begin{theorem}[Pause (text)]
    a + b = \pause c
  \end{theorem}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Writing `{\pause}` also works and doesn't freeze the spacing in the formula.