Beamer: \pause creates unwanted newlines in math
I would like to have pauses in my beamer presentation when displaying a slide containing math. However, the \pause command creates unwanted newlines and makes the text box too high.
Code looks like this:
\begin{frame}
  $$ 1 + 1 = 2$$\pause
  $$ f(x) = x^2$$
\end{frame}

Actual code:
\begin{frame}{DOUBLON} % TODO Titre + axes + pauses
    $$\vec P = -mg \vec u_y$$\pause
    $$\vec f(t) = -\lambda \vec v(t)$$ \pause
    $$m \vec a = \sum{\vec F_{ext}}$$\pause
    $$\dot{\vec v} = -g \vec u_y + \frac{- \lambda}{m} \vec v$$\pause
    $$\vec v(t) = \begin{bmatrix}\pause
        v_x(t)\\
        v_y(t)
    \end{bmatrix}$$\pause
    $$\begin{bmatrix}
        \dot{v_x}(t)\\
        \dot{v_y}(t)
    \end{bmatrix} =
    \begin{bmatrix}
        -\frac{\lambda}{m} v_x(t)\\
        \frac{-\lambda}{m} v_y(t) -g \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$
\end{frame}

First picture is without pauses, second is with pauses.



Unrelated, $$... $$ should not be used in any latex document

The \par\pause\noindent at the end of the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75822/36296 works fine
