# Strange disappearing colored rules in beamer

Tags: beamer, color, rules, colortbl

I have received a `booktabs` bug report of `\cmidrule`s that disappear when coloured rules are used inside `beamer` (together with `colortbl`). The problem can be illustrated with the following simple code and looks like an interaction between the `beamer` colour setup and `\leaders`. In the normal Latex classes the code is fine.

I know to little about the inner workings of `beamer` and hope there is someone here who can help or that can give a workaround. Note that the colour need to be grouped inside `booktabs` to prevent leaking.

**EDIT:** In an e-mail Michael Palmer suggested the addition of a `\kern` at the end of the grouping. This seems to work but the question is WHY?

> **Note:** The standard tabular `\cline` also disappears inside `beamer` when the line color is set with the `\arrayrulecolor` of the `colortbl` package. So this is now also David Carlisle's problem :-)

**Beamer class**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand\tfillA[3]{\makebox[#1]{#2\leaders\hrule\hfill#3}}
\newcommand\tfillB[3]{\makebox[#1]{\color{red}#2\leaders\hrule\hfill#3}}
\newcommand\tfillC[3]{\makebox[#1]{#2{\color{red}\leaders\hrule\hfill}#3}}
\newcommand\tfillD[3]{\makebox[#1]{#2{\color{red}\leaders\hrule\hfill\kern0pt}#3}}%<--Edit

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    INSIDE BEAMER CLASS\par\smallskip
    \tfillA{2cm}{A}{B}: Works fine without colour\par
    \tfillB{2cm}{A}{B}: Works fine with ungrouped colour\par
    \tfillC{2cm}{A}{B}: Rule disappears with grouped colour\par
    \tfillD{2cm}{A}{B}: Rule reappears with kern at end ?????
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Article class**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\tfillA[3]{\makebox[#1]{#2\leaders\hrule\hfill#3}}
\newcommand\tfillB[3]{\makebox[#1]{\color{red}#2\leaders\hrule\hfill#3}}
\newcommand\tfillC[3]{\makebox[#1]{#2{\color{red}\leaders\hrule\hfill}#3}}

\begin{document}
    INSIDE ARTICLE CLASS\par\smallskip
    \tfillA{2cm}{A}{B}: Works fine without colour\par
    \tfillB{2cm}{A}{B}: Works fine with colour  everywhere\par
    \tfillC{2cm}{A}{B}: Works fine with grouped colour
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this also works: `\makebox[#1]{#2{\color{red}\hrulefill}#3}` I suppose a problem with `\leaders`

Comment: @Herbert: The problem is that the `\cmidrule` in booktabs (and the standard `\cline`) uses `\leaders` internally. The `colortbl` package has the same problem inside beamer

Comment: the definition of `\hrulefill` also uses the `\kern\z@`. I have no idea why it is important for beamer.

Comment: `\null` also works.

Comment: a `\kern` after `\leaders` is usually to protect it from `\unskip` As for the note I might look but colortbl documentation says not to use `\cline` so any behaviour is user error.

Comment: adding tracingall to your version C shows `\reset@color ->\beamer@lastskip =\lastskip ....ifhmode \unskip ` so as suspected beamer's `\unskipping` where it should not.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Beamer, for whatever reason, redefines the latex color command `\reset@color` to do an unskip. That normally removes preceding white space, which you can save and restore with `\lastskip` but unfortunately `\lastkip` and `\unskip` "work" with `\leaders` but `\lastskip` only saves the glue component and so no record that there are leaders there is possible in classic tex (or etex).

All LaTeX `\leader` commands have a trailing `\kern` or box to prevent this, otherwise several standard commands including `\newline` which similarly do an `\unskip` would destroy `\dotfill` etc. (The LaTeX definition of `\dotfill` adds this, the original plain TeX one does not have it).

So while it is a bit surprising that Beamer does this, it is generally the case that a leaders followed by unknown commands ought to have the `\kern` there. `\reset@color` is inserted by `\aftergroup` at the closing `}` which is why the problem only affects the version that closes the group immediately after the leader. One could argue (not unreasonably) that `\reset@color` should not be an "unknown" command. Obviously it would be easy to patch it not to do that but without knowing the details of beamers workings and why it was changed, that may not be the best thing to do.

Comment: It looks then if a trailing `\kern\z@` to protects against unskips is the best option to safeguard the code. It also works for `colortbl` if you add it to `\@cline`.

Comment: See [this answer of mine](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73729) for an explanation of why `beamer` does this. In short, the overlay commands add `\pdfliteral`s that would influence `\lastskip` without the `\unskip` business. So the `\kern\z@` after the leader seems to be the way to go. (Ping, @Danie.)

Comment: Is there already a solution for this, with a patch or so?

Comment: @cacamailg as discussed there isn't a patch required you just need to define your command so that the leaders is followed by `\kern0pt` or `\mbox{}` or anything else that will protect it from `\unskip`