# \cmidrule with booktabs in beamer does not show up

Tags: beamer, rules, booktabs

I am trying to use a coloured `\cmidrule` in a table in `beamer` - however, it does not show up. I have read [Strange disappearing colored rules in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99041/strange-disappearing-colored-rules-in-beamer) which indicates that this is a bug and discusses reasons and some possibilities to fix things by adding `\kern`. However, it does not actually show how to apply this to `\cmidrule`, just to other `\hrule` commands. My questions is: how do I apply this to `\cmidrule`? or is that not feasible?

MWE

```
\documentclass[pdftex,12pt,fleqn,xcolor=pdftex,table,usepdftitle=false]{beamer}
\pdfpageattr{/Group <</S /Transparency /I true /CS /DeviceRGB>>} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bera}
\usepackage{arevmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usecolortheme{shark}
\useoutertheme[glossy]{wuerzburg}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{booktabs with cmidrule}
\rowcolors*{2}{black!5}{structure!22}\arrayrulecolor{structure}
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrrr}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{Penalty} \\
\cmidrule{2-7}
$\hat{\lambda}_{i}$ 
& None & a & b & c & d& e \\
\midrule
1 &    10&  -11&   -4&   -8&    8 & 3\\
2 &    10&  -11&   -4&   -8&    8 & 3\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There always have been some problems with `booktabs` and `colortbl` although in v1.6180 of `booktabs` they have been tackled. So in this case it seems to be some additional interference with `beamer` since trying this with `report` i get correct results. (BTW rules and colored rows is a pretty ugly thing)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Commenting on the linked question, Herbert states

> I suppose a problem with `\leaders` [...] the definition of `\hrulefill` also uses the `\kern\z@` [...]

The definition of `\hrulefill` is

```
\leavevmode\leaders\hrule\hfill\kern\z@
```

The `booktabs` commands that include `\leaders` in their definition are `\@cmiderulea` and `\@cmidruleb`:

```
\def\@cmidrulea{%
   \multispan\@cmidla&\multispan\@cmidlb
   \unskip\hskip\cmrkern@l%
  {\CT@arc@\leaders\hrule \@height\@thisrulewidth\hfill}%
   \hskip\cmrkern@r\cr}%
\def\@cmidruleb{%
    \multispan\@cmidlb
    \unskip\hskip \cmrkern@l%
   {\CT@arc@\leaders\hrule \@height\@thisrulewidth\hfill}%
    \hskip\cmrkern@r\cr}%
```

It seemed worth a try to add `\kern\z@` after `\hfill` to both definitions. (For convenience, I used the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package to do so.) And indeed:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,12pt,fleqn,xcolor=pdftex,table,usepdftitle=false]{beamer}
\pdfpageattr{/Group <</S /Transparency /I true /CS /DeviceRGB>>} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bera}
\usepackage{arevmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usecolortheme{shark}
%\useoutertheme[glossy]{wuerzburg}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@cmidrulea}{\hfill}{\hfill\kern\z@}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@cmidruleb}{\hfill}{\hfill\kern\z@}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{booktabs with cmidrule}
\rowcolors*{2}{black!5}{structure!22}\arrayrulecolor{structure}
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrrr}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{Penalty} \\
\cmidrule{2-7}
$\hat{\lambda}_{i}$ 
& None & a & b & c & d& e \\
\midrule
1 &    10&  -11&   -4&   -8&    8 & 3\\
2 &    10&  -11&   -4&   -8&    8 & 3\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]