# clines stop working after using the tabularx key in tcolorbox

Tags: beamer, tcolorbox

I suspect this may be a bug but I'm not completely sure, so I posted here before contacting the relevant package mantainer to ask your opinion.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

 \begin{tcolorbox}[tabularx={X|X}]
 1 & 2 \\
 3 & 4
 \end{tcolorbox}

 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X|X}
 \hline
  1 & 2 \\\cline{2-2}
  3 & 4 \\
 \hline
 \end{tabularx}

 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

In the above code the `\cline` command does not work as expected. This happens when a `tabularx` key is used in a tcolorbox and only happens in `beamer`. If you switch the class to, say, `article`, the cline works.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the same issue as

[Strange disappearing colored rules in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99041/strange-disappearing-colored-rules-in-beamer/99156#99156)

Although that may not be initially obvious:-)

[image]

You can protect the `\cline` by adding a kern.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\makeatletter
\def\@cline#1-#2\@nil{%
  \omit
  \@multicnt#1%
  \advance\@multispan\m@ne
  \ifnum\@multicnt=\@ne\@firstofone{&\omit}\fi
  \@multicnt#2%
  \advance\@multicnt-#1%
  \advance\@multispan\@ne
  \leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill\kern\z@
  \cr
  \noalign{\vskip-\arrayrulewidth}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

 \begin{tcolorbox}[tabularx={X|X}]
 1 & 2 \\
 3 & 4
 \end{tcolorbox}

 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X|X}
 \hline
  1 & 2 \\\cline{2-2}
  3 & 4 \\
 \hline
 \end{tabularx}

 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```