# cline disappears in beamer

Tags: beamer

I took the following code from another question, but it does not work here:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{colortbl,xcolor}
\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tabular}{c@{\,}l@{}}
                         & $p$ \\\arrayrulecolor{blue!60!green!70}    & $p \to q$ \\\cline{2-2}
        $\therefore$         & $q$ \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

What should I do to have a blue cline?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Thanks for providing a MWE, it really helps :) Could you provide a link to the original question from which you got your code?

Comment: @cmhughes hey, hi, I think this is the same issue as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99041/strange-disappearing-colored-rules-in-beamer?rq=1 but I couldn't find a way to convert the answer into a solution for my case. I can't find the question from which I got the code anymore :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

LaTeX's color implementation inserts a color special and resets the color via `\reset@color` after the current group. Here this is done after the colored rule that is drawn via `\leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill`. Class class `beamer` redefines `\reset@color`. This redefinition introduces an `\unskip` that kills the previous `\leaders`. Thus the line vanishes.

The following patch adds an invisible `\kern0pt` after the
`\leaders` command to prevent `\unskip` from killing the `\leaders` skip.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% after package colortbl is loaded
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@cline
  {\arrayrulewidth\hfill}% search
  {\arrayrulewidth\hfill\kern\z@}% replace
  {}% success
  {\errmessage{Patching \string\@cline\space failed}}% failure
\makeatother

% make the rule thicker
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{2\arrayrulewidth}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{tabular}{c@{\,}l@{}}
      & $p$ \\\arrayrulecolor{blue!60!green!70}    & $p
      \to q$ \\\cline{2-2}
      $\therefore$         & $q$ \\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]